# I need a countif with multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

How can I count cell with multiple conditions one of which if cell $J:$J does not contain the word FREE, I have this but it does not work for me

```
=COUNTIFS(Results!$C:$C,$A$2,Results!$B:$B,A34,Results!$H:$H,$F$6,Results!$J:$J,"!*FREE*")
```

for some unknown reason, the above formula is not showing the asterisks around the !FREE I can see then when editing this question but they disappear when I save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if cell $J:$J does not contain the word FREE

```
=COUNTIFS(Results!$C:$C, $A$2,
          Results!$B:$B, A34,
          Results!$H:$H, $F$6,
          Results!$J:$J, "<>FREE")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=COUNTIFS(Results!$C:$C, $A$2,
          Results!$B:$B, A34,
          Results!$H:$H, $F$6,
          Results!$J:$J, "<>*FREE*")
```

[image: 0]